# How/which formula to use, to show combine text results for false condition (for pending task reporting usage)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Wanted to check if CONCATENATE is the one to use (not sure if my excel has TEXTJOIN), and how to show just the text that has empty value in the cells.

For example in my attachment below, I want the intended result shown like in B2 and B3, where the texts shown with delimiter, when the values are false (empty).

If I were to use CONCATENATE like in Row 10 and Row 11, it's rather manual and it only capture "positive values" as in non-blank cells.

Purpose: To show pending tasks (empty/blank status cells)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you have CONCAT, then you have TEXTJOIN. Just try `=TEXTJOIN(",",1,{"A","B","C"})`. If that gives you "A,B,C", then you have TEXTJOIN. If that is the case, then perhaps what is blocking you from using Euler's solution is FILTER. Then you need a workaround for that.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick the OP is using `CONCATENATE` which is different than `CONCAT`.  `CONCATENATE` is available in all versions of Excel, while `CONCAT` is only available in Office 365 and Excel 2019.

Comment: Hey @ScottCraner - I didn't know that. That's really an old function. In any case, I cannot see a way to bring it together with CONCATENATE. Seems a nearly useless function in modern Excel.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick in my opinion it has been useless since its inception.  The fact that I can use `&` to do the same thing without having to type `CONCATENATE` makes it tedious to use.

Comment: thanks guys, appreciate the comments, been busy doing other stuff so yeah haven't got the time to really try it out, and i usually study the provided formulas too and it'll take time, will try both and post the results as soon possible,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MID with CONCATENATED IFS:

```
=MID(IF(C2="","/"&$C$1,"")&IF(D2="","/"&$D$1,"")&IF(E2="","/"&$E$1,"")&IF(F2="","/"&$F$1,"")&IF(GC2="","/"&$G$1,"")&IF(H2="","/"&$H$1,""),2,999)
```

[image]

Comment: =MID(IF(C2="","/"&$C$1,"")&IF(D2="","/"&$D$1,"")&IF(E2="","/"&$E$1,"")&IF(F2="","/"&$F$1,"")&IF(G2="","/"&$G$1,"")&IF(H2="","/"&$H$1,""),2,999)

this one works in my current excel on the testing sheet thanks @Scott Craner
will try on a working files later and see how it goes if its work with merged cells and if the data interfere with other formula

Answer (score 1):

I would use `TEXJOIN` and `FILTER` if you have the newest version of Excel.

For example: `=TEXTJOIN("/",1,FILTER($E$2:$I$2, ISBLANK(E3:I3)))`

[image]

EDIT: For older versions, a temporary workaround is as follows:

1. make a temporary array the same size as your original dataframe where each value is determined by a formula such as `=IF(ISBLANK(E3), E$2&"/","")`
2. Use something like `=LEFT(CONCAT(E15:J15), LEN(CONCAT(E15:J15))-1)` to get the desired result (where E15:J15 is where I elected to store the first row of the temporary array created in step 1).

Comment: Hi there, just tried it and yeah apparently I'm still equipped with the older version since I'm not able to use that function. Is there any function similar text join? I can only relate back to CONCATENATE, in which I've tried albeit lacking the understanding how-to's. 

However I'll try to import my files to Gsheet and make some arrangement and testing, hopefully it works as per my intended.

Comment: @Dick Vun Dang, not really sure how to get it in one go then. See my comment for a workaround that might help, but importing to Google Sheets and working from there isn't a bad idea either. Hope it works out for you!

Comment: @Euler'sDisgracedStepchild just an FYI, If they do not have TEXTJOIN, they do not have CONCAT.  They came out at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of your Excel version, but I think this would work in older versions *(formatted for readability - will work if you paste it directly into cell B2 and copy down)*:

```
=LEFT(CONCAT( INDEX( CHOOSE({1;2;3},$C$1:$H$1,{"/","/","/","/","/","/"},{"","","","","",""}),
                     INDEX( IF(ISBLANK(C2:H2),{1;2},{3;3}),
                            MOD(COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,,12))-1,2)+1,
                            (COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,,12))-1)/2+1 ),
                     (COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,,12))-1)/2+1 ) ),
      SUM(7*ISBLANK(C2:H2))-1 )
```

[image: result]

**Notes**

- As this is an array formula, you may have to enter it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> with an older version of Excel.
- The stat labels must all have a length of 6 characters as shown in your post. If not, then they must at least have the same length and the last line `SUM(7*ISBLANK(C2:H2))-1` must be changed to replace the 7 with the string length + 1, e.g. a length of 9 would be `SUM(10*ISBLANK(C2:H2))-1`.
- If they don't have the same length, the LEFT( can be removed along with the `SUM(10*ISBLANK(C2:H2))-1)` at the end. You will end up having a trailing / delimiter at the end. You could fix that for the case of stat F being the last part by changing `{"/","/","/","/","/","/"}` to `{"/","/","/","/","/",""}`, but the other cases would still have a trailing /. Another approach is much more complex, but the component `SUM(10*ISBLANK(C2:H2))-1)` could be shaped to identify what to cut off or maybe a helper column could be built - in any case, let's hope your situation is that the stat labels all have the same length.
- The delimiter "/" can be changed, but must always be a single character. If not, then then last line must be changed to `SUM( [label length + delimiter length] *ISBLANK(C2:H2))-1`.
- This formula is fixed to 6 stat columns. If you need for it to accommodate more, it is possible by extending the `{"/","/","/","/","/","/"}` and `{"","","","","",""}` (one element for each new column) and replacing every 12 with 2 times the number of columns. Also, obviously, the references **$C$1:$H$1** and **C1:H2** must be changed to read in your new columns.